# How to start with Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm not completely new to Android and understand the most basics. But I have still some issues with template-activities like Navigation Drawer.

What is currently the best way to learn about that? There are a lot of new features and most of the tutorials are pretty old

Thank you very much

Comment: Please take your time to add some detailed explanation about what you're trying to achieve and add the code of what you tried so far

Comment: I have several different projects. I think this would be too much to share and is not really important for this topic. I have some new app ideas that i want to implement and I wanted to improve my knowledge to get a better understanding of the navigation drawer.

Comment: If you're looking for the resources to learn how to implement navigation drawer in your application you can find a lot of tutorials in YouTube and other sites. At SO you can raise your issues you faced while coding and people at here will try to solve with their answers but ain't no one got time to coach you. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am goint to explain how to implement navigation drawer step by step. Whatever doubts come in your mind then just google it. I explain most of the things in comment.

Step :1) Create DrawerLayout in xml layout lets say activity_main.xml And also add navigation view inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" <!--it will fit it in full system window-->
    tools:openDrawer="start" <!--it means that the drawer open from left side-->
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"  <!-- it specify where you want to show icon -->
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" <!-- it include header-->
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_menu" /> <!-- it inlude menu means the items below the header-->

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Step :2) create app_bar_main.xml for toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Step :3) Create content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Step :4) create nav_header_main.xml for header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp" <!-- you set the height of header-->
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_blue">

  <!--add here whatever you want to show in header of navigation drawer-->


</LinearLayout>
```

Step 5:) create activity_main_drawer_menu.xml for menu items below the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:title="About"/>

    </group>

</menu>
```

Step :6)finally create MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView=navigationView.getHeaderView(0); //here you can take view of header


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        fragment=new yourFragment();  //here you add which fragment you want to display at the starting
        ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id=item.getItemId();

        if (id==R.id.nav_home) {
            fragment=new yourFragment();
        }
        else if (id==R.id.nav_about) {
            fragment=new yourFragment();
        }

        

        ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        super.onPause();
    }
```